# Tiny lstlisting in multicols makes columns unbalanced

Tags: listings, multicol, incompatibility

I stumbled along a strange effect. Consider the following example of two columns of numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\tiny]
1
2
3
4
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I expect this to produce two columns with the same number of rows. The first should contain 1 and 2, the second should contain 3 and 4. Unfortunately, I got the following unbalanced columns:
[image: image of the error]
This error only occurs when either the `xcolor` or `tikz` package is loaded, and only when the basicstyle of `lstlisting` is set to either `\tiny` or `\scriptsize`. I have absolutely no clue why this is happening.

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hmm, tricky. `lstlisting` adds `aboveskip` and `belowskip` before and after the environment (and by default they are about 6pt). Now since the listing starts as the first item in the multicol, the `aboveskip` is dropped as all vertical space is dropped at the very beginning. But the `belowskip` remains which means that we do not have 4 lines but more or less 5 (and the last one some empty white space).

so one way to fix that is to set

```
  \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\tiny,belowskip=0pt]
```

The use of `multicols=2` works for the same reason, because now the skips are added outside of multicol not inside.

I should probably add that `multicols`normally also removes vartical space at the end of the last column to ensure that balancing works well. However, the `belowskip` space added by `lstlisting` is actually hidden as it is followed by a) an additional skip of 0pt and b) a color change, i.e., what we have there is

```
.\penalty -50
.\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0      % <-- that's belowskip
.\glue 0.0
.\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
```

so multicol has no chance to remove it. I think this could be considered a bug in `listings` as such spaces should be accessible from  the outside, e.g., it should be able to interact with `\addvspace` which is also not possible due to the colorstack command.

Perhaps this should be brought to the attention of the the listings maintainer(s).

Answer (score 4):

When the `multicol` package is loaded, it can be used to typeset multi-column
listings. These are specified with the `multicols` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[multicols=2,basicstyle=\tiny]
1
2
3
4
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That indeed solves the problem. My first question remains: why does this happen?